# How to parse end of line string in Java

Tags: java

I would like to read a text file which has some strings such as:

```
abc  
def

ghi  
jkl

mno  
pqr
```

I am using a while loop to read only a pair and store them in an arraylist. I would like to stop as soon I encounter an empty line (`\n`) e.g. after `def`. But my code wont work ... what am I doing wrong?

```
while(!"\n".equals(sCurrentLine)) {
     -- do stuff --
}
```

Comment: while(!"".equals(sCurrentLine)) ?

Comment: What kind of reader do you use? Try `!sCurrentLine.equals("")`

Comment: Do you use `readLine()` to read your lines? If so, you need to check for `""`, because `readLine()` does *not* include the trailing newline.

Comment: remove \n also from "\n"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are reading line by line then empty line is empty line (`""`), not `"\n"` which is string of length 1

You may also need check that there's **no more lines** in this case `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns null

Comment: he wants to read one pair, then there is a line with line separator, then there is another pair, so there is not empty line which he can use as condition!

Comment: According to his example, there is one after each pair

Comment: and thats the problem: he want's to break just after the first pair. so he has to check for line separator ("\n")

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach, empty string are readed as "", not "\n" (using BufferedReader, at least), even if there are more lines. [Example](http://ideone.com/FuFOfl) (quite long, but it's autogenerated, usedful code is in the top), see second output

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach readLine() doesn't return line terminators: it removes them: see the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

You are making one big mistake: you're assuming that the newline character is `\n`, which is not always true. Depending on the operating system it can be either `CR`, `LF` or `CRLF`.

You can keep checking it your way, but you'd have to check it against all these three possibilities.

You can also use `String.trim()` and then compare the string `"".equals(var.trim())`

Comment: His 'big mistake' is the same as your big mistake: not knowing that readLine() *removes* the line terminators. So what they are is completely irrelevant. -1

Comment: @EJP how do you know he's reading using `readline()`? It's not shown in his code. If he really does, then you're right, but since I don't know that, my answer stands. Anyway, this may be useful to someone in the future, constantly reminding everybody of encodings and endlines is like 10% of SO;)

Answer (score 2):

```
 while(!"".equals(sCurrentLine)) {
 -- do stuff --
 }
```

This will help you

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddToArrayList {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("D:\\Text.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<>();
    String s=null;
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        s=sc.nextLine();
        if(s.equals("")){
             continue;
        }
        str.add(s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. You need to say *why* this answers the question. You also need to justify your switch from readLine() to Scanner, which is in fact completely pointless. There is only one line here that is actually relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

Assumption 1,  you are to add pairs skipping empty lines.

```
    String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          //when we encounter a empty line we continue
          //the loop without doing anything
          if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
               continue;
          }
          //add to list
        }
```

Assumption 2, you want to exit at first empty line

```
 String line = null;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      //when we encounter a empty line we exit the loop
      if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
          //break the loop
          break;
      }
      //add to list
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of using a system dependent String.

Comment: This won't help, if you are reading file created on another system.

Comment: It won't help at all if you're using readLine(), as the OP is.